# www to non-www with removing extensions htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i've removed .php extensions first on my website. then i've forwarded www to non-www version. but there is a problem with that.

my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^188\.166\.104\.194
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

www forwards to non-www with that .htaccess. that is cool. but the problem is with the other files.

i'm now using: http://example.com/contact instead of: http://example.com/contact.php

but when you try to open http://www.example.com/contact that .htaccess forwards me to http://example.com/contact.php/

how do i fix that?

have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of rules and some refactoring:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.example\.com|188\.166\.104\.194)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php [L]
```

Make sure to test is after clearing your browser cache.